# Decode serialized cookie and loop options

Tags: php, cookies, serialization, deserialization

I store form elements as serialized data in a cookie.

On another page I want to collect this cookie but the cookie contains this string:

```
form_key=kcE3W2vzParNhPN5&options%5B1508%5D=2025&options%5B1509%5D=1234&options%5B1510%5D=5678&options%5B1511%5D=&options%5B1512%5D=&options%5B1513%5D=&productId=59891
```

%5B and %5D are brackets I figured, but how can I look through all these options in the string and get their ID + value into an array with PHP.

So from above string I would like to create an array with:

```
arr = array (

[1508] = '2025';
[1509] = '1234';
[1510] = '5678';
[1511] = '';
[1512] = '';

);
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is [`parse_str()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
$str = "form_key=kcE3W2vzParNhPN5&options%5B1508%5D=2025&options%5B1509%5D=1234&options%5B1510%5D=5678&options%5B1511%5D=&options%5B1512%5D=&options%5B1513%5D=&productId=59891";

$output = array();
parse_str($str, $output);

print_r($output); // $output['options'] will contain your array you're looking for.
```

See execution [here](https://3v4l.org/TR27p):

```
Array
(
    [form_key] => kcE3W2vzParNhPN5
    [options] => Array
        (
            [1508] => 2025
            [1509] => 1234
            [1510] => 5678
            [1511] => 
            [1512] => 
            [1513] => 
        )

    [productId] => 59891
)
```